# Pseudocode on pop up alert using bar chart data

Tags: javascript, json, database, api, charts

I have a basic bar chart that retrieves data from my database and this data is stored into this chart on the front-end.

1) The data is not in an array
2) The data is not in a file
3) JSON.parse will not help in my particular situation

4) The data receives a JSON response via API and authentication

My question is, for web developers, in Javascript, how exactly do I go about developing that analysing a json request to find a certain number is over 10, as an example and for this particular situation.

No data is stored in the coding. But I imagine is there a way to read this data through the console using the javascript? If so, please point me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Why does JSON.parse not help if it is a JSON response?

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(..)) , the rest is up to you

Comment: Thanks, I will recheck my javascript and test this again as I do not have any arrays objects declared or set anywhere in my code.